# What's wrong with Registry.GetValue?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I trying to get a registry value:

```
var value = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography", "MachineGuid", 0);
```

In Windows XP all ok, but in Windows 7 returns 0. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography` using regedit I see `MachineGuid`, but if I run

```
var keys = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("Cryptography", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree).GetValueNames();
```

`keys.Length` is 0.

What do I do wrong? With other values all ok in both of OS.

Comment: It's showing MachineGuid for me on Windows 7. Is your user an admin? Maybe it's a permissions issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if this may be it, but are you using 64 or 32 bit Windows 7?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that you probably are compiling the solution as x86, if you compile as x64 you can read the values.

Try the following code compiling as x86 and x64:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MachineGUID:" + MachineGUID);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string MachineGUID
    {
        get
        {
            Guid guidMachineGUID;
            if (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography") != null)
            {
                if (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography").GetValue("MachineGuid") != null)
                {
                    guidMachineGUID = new Guid(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography").GetValue("MachineGuid").ToString());
                    return guidMachineGUID.ToString();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129.aspx).

You can found in [here](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/) a way of reading values in x86 and x64.

Comment: +1 for this excellent hint. I had exactly this trouble in Windows 7 / 64 bit and the article "You can find in here a way of reading values in x86 and x64" solved it. Thank you, pedrocgsousa !!!

Comment: Just another tip for others: If you open the registry the normal way, then HKLM\Software\YourVendorID does not work if your application is 64 bit - it will always open HKLM\Software\Microsoft instead. Use `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);` as described in the article to open HKLM and subsequent OpenSubKey calls will work as expected!

Answer (score 7):

It probably has to do with UAC (User Account Control). The extra layer of protection for Windows Vista and Windows 7.

You'll need to request permissions to the registry.

**EDIT**:
Your code right now:

```
var keys = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE")
    .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
    .OpenSubKey("Cryptography", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
    .GetValueNames();
```

Only requests the permissions on the Cryptography subkey, maybe that causes the problem (at least I had that once), so the new code would then be:

```
var keys = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
    .OpenSubKey("Microsoft", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
    .OpenSubKey("Cryptography", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
    .GetValueNames();
```

**EDIT2:**
I attached the debugger to it, on this code:

```
var key1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
var key2 = key1.OpenSubKey("Microsoft", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
var key3 = key2.OpenSubKey("Cryptography", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
var key4 = key3.GetValueNames();
```

It turns out, you can read that specific value, at least that's my guess, because all data is correct, until I open key3, there the ValueCount is zero, instead of the expected 1.

I think it's a special value that's protected.

Comment: With other keys all ok. Only that key is problem

Comment: I was thinking the same, but wouldn't that throw [the SecurityException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx)?

Comment: I can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't work except permissions. I checked it on my Windows 7 x64 operating system, and the key is just there. What exception does it throw when you try it?

Comment: No exeption, just return NULL

Comment: Yes, that's what I said too... It's the exact same code, just debuggable.

Comment: Maybe you know any other not protected value in registry which can be used as computer identificator?

Comment: Okay, well what you should know is that the MachineGuid is NOT unique, it's just a random variable, I don't know what you're using it for, but if it's networking, then I suppose the MAC address and IP address are better, but they aren't also fail safe.

Answer (score 6):

You say you're on 64-bit Windows: is your app 32-bit?  If so it's probably being affected by [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx) and is looking at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography`. You may have to P/Invoke to work around it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129.aspx.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why my edited value is not returned. This saved my day, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If you're not an administrator, you only have read permission on HKLM. You need to open the key read-only instead. Not sure how to do that with .NET's Registry class; with the API directly, you use [RegOpenKeyEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `KEY_READ` flag.</strike>

EDIT: After checking MSDN, I see that [OpenSubKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx) does open read only, and returns the contents if it succeeds and nothing if it fails. Since you're chaining multiple OpenSubKey calls, it's most likely one of them that's failing that causes the others to fail. Try breaking them out into separate calls, and checking the intermediate values returned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to the party, but, none of the solutions worked for me.

This is how I've solved this issue:

```
public static Guid GetMachineGuid
    {
        get
        {
            var machineGuid = Guid.Empty;

            var localMachineX64View = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            var cryptographySubKey = localMachineX64View.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography");
            
            if (cryptographySubKey == null) return machineGuid;
            
            var machineGuidValue = (string)cryptographySubKey.GetValue("MachineGuid");

            Guid.TryParse(machineGuidValue, out machineGuid);

            return machineGuid;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem when i imported Microsoft.Win32 and changed the application-settings to x64 like pedrocgsousa mentioned.