# Getting windows serial number (MachineGuid) in both x86 and x64 architectures

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

I´m currently using the following C++ code to get the `MachineGuid` from the windows registry and use that information for my licensing algorithm:

```
std::wstring key = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography";
std::wstring name = L"MachineGuid";

HKEY hKey;

if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not open registry key");

DWORD type;
DWORD cbData;

if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, &type, NULL, &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not read registry value");
}

if (type != REG_SZ)
{
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    throw "Incorrect registry value type";
}

std::wstring value(cbData/sizeof(wchar_t), L'\0');
if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&value[0]), &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    throw "Could not read registry value";
}

RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

This works pretty well on a x86 system (32 bit). Now I´ve migrated the whole code to x64 (64bit) Windows and the `RegQueryValueEx` call is returning error.

Among some other posts, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213020/getting-windows-serial-number-was-getting-machineguid-from-registry) explains very clearly why this does not work on 64bit machines, and offers an alternative for both 32bit and 64bit using the `ManagementObject` class from `System.Management.dll`. The problem is that this solution works on C#, not on C++. I can´t find out a C++ equivalent of the `ManagementObject` class.

So, what is the correct solution for the problem: Getting the window serial number (`MachineGuid`) on both x86 and x64 machines using C++.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: WMI is available to C++ applications through COM APIs. I recommend looking at [Creating a WMI Application using C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762(v=vs.85).aspx). You'll be looking to execute a WQL Query (similar to SQL) to query one of the [Win32_Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792258(v=vs.85).aspx) classes.

What I can't tell you at this point is which one contains the equivalent of the `MachineGuid`. [Win32_ComputerSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx) may be your starting point.

Comment: Should you continue to pursue a WMI solution, [Win32_ComputerSystemProduct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394105(v=vs.85).aspx) `UUID` which relates to UUIDs found in the Windows OS System Information application is what I could find at a quick glance that may relate to the `MachineGuid`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` bit to your RegOpenKeyEx argument. Like this:

```
RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey )
```

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx) says it’s ignored on 32-bit OSes, so you don’t even need to detect WOW64.

P.S. I don’t recommend WMI, it’s too slow. I currently have i5-4460 CPU, 16GB RAM, relatively fast SSD, and yet WMI takes 1-2 seconds to initialize and run even a simple query.

Comment: Thanks... Should I add the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` for both 32bit and 64bit implementations of only for 64-bit option and keep the 32bit without it ?

Comment: Just for 32 bit will work, but it's harmless to add for both.