# GetSubKeyNames NullReferenceExceptuon was unhandled

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a program that checks registry key for installed software. It was fine until recently it gets "Has stopped working" message when try to open. Seems caused by Windows updates.

```
Dim SoftwareKey As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products"
        Using rk As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey)
            For Each skName As String In rk.GetSubKeyNames
```

`rk.GetSubKeyNames` returns NullReferenceExceptuon - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But the above code works fine If I target it as AnyCPU or X64. Not sure what caused this and why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Probably `rk` is `null` because there is no such registry key anymore?

Comment: Then why it works fine when compiled as AnyCPU or x64?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5262830/1070452